# How to save excel file in csv format?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using excel 2013, and I want to save an excel file with(.xlsx) format to (csv) format without any problem, because i want to use this file in weka program, but when I tried to save it in this format I got a problem (some features in your workbook might be lost if you save it as comma separated values (.csv)) .

The file image is attached below, but how i can attach the file in my question?.

[image: my excel file]

Answer (score 3):

CSV files is a text format. CSV stands for Comma Separated Values.

An Excel file (XLSX) is far more than just a string of texts, separated by commas. It has information about fonts, colors, and other things like borders and how big a cell is.

It is logical that when you save a file as CSV, you will lose everything the CSV does not support. There is no other way around it, but is almost always good enough.

See if the created CSV file can be imported in your Weka program, I bet it can.

Comment: i tried to import csv file in weka but i got an error .

Comment: CSV can have different layouts. For example: `"a","b"`, `"a";"b"`,`a,b` and even `a {tab} b`. see if weka has support for different layouts and if not, export as a different kind of CSV from excel.

Comment: When i tried to save this file with (csv) format to (arff) format using weka i got an error loading file message ( java.io.IOException:6 problem encountered on line :2)

Comment: Here are some official articles for your reference:[mport or export text (.txt or .csv) files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba); [Save a workbook to text format (.txt or .csv)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-a-workbook-to-text-format-txt-or-csv-3e9a9d6c-70da-4255-aa28-fcacf1f081e6) .